# AMQP 1.0 and transactions

Tags: .net, azure, amqp, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am evaluating AMQP 1.0 together with Azure Service Bus and currently looking into transaction support - 2 phase commit coordinating a database insert/update/delete with read/write of messages to the bus).
Using "Amqp.Net Lite" for .Net in my tests.

- Does Azure Service Bus support 2PC transactions?
- Does AMQP 1.0 and Amqp.Net Lite support 2PC transactions? (any code examples?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Azure Service Bus support 2PC transactions?

No.

> Does AMQP 1.0 and Amqp.Net Lite support 2PC transactions? (any code examples?)

No.

You can find the samples under [AMQP.NET Lite repo](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/)

Why there are no 2PC transactions? You're in the cloud environment and resources not only are service-based but also distant. 2PC over multiple resources with a distributed transaction controller to coordinate it all will time out. For Azure Service Bus and AMQP.NET Lite there **is** support for transactions, [transport level transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions). I.e. you can receive/send messages in a transactional manner, but no other service can participate in that transaction. You would need to change your implementation architecture to deal with idempotency.

There was a good Twitter series on [2PC and cloud](https://twitter.com/i/moments/823828050538364928) you might find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer